# Populating a dropdownlist based on a previous dropdownlist selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

within my ASP website I have two dropdown lists, the first has four options that a user selects and based on this the second dropdownlist will be populated from the selected database column data. I am trying to populate these lists programmatically rather than binding them through a data source

The code I currently has has two issues:

**1. Within my 'onselectedIndex changed' method I cannot trigger my event if I wish to click the first element in the dropdown list, I have to click another item then re-click the first for it too trigger. I do have AutoPostBack set to true**

**2. When the event does trigger the database data is not populating the second dropdownlist, It is correctly populating with the correct amount of rows for the dataset, but not displaying the data.**

Once the first element is chosen from the first dropdown list i.e 'coffee Name' then the second list populates with the correct row numbers i.e 3 but not with the right data

Current code:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string option = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        // If the selected element is 'Coffee Name' run the method.
        if (option == "Coffee Name")
        {
            bindCoffeeNames();
        }
    }



    private void bindCoffeeNames()
    {
        Query the DB and bind the data to the second dropdown list.
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select coffeeName from Coffees ORDER BY coffeeName ASC", sqlcon);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DropDownList2.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Autopostback will only fire on change. You want to insert a default placeholder to a
   dropdownlist. you can do it in code like this:

   ```
   dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select an item", String.Empty));
   dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex = 0;
   ```

   Or in markup:

   ```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPersons" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="Name">
   <asp:ListItem> -- please select person -- </asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   ```
2. Add this line to bindCoffeeNames:

   `DropDownList2.DataTextField = "coffeeName";`

Also, it is a good idea to have a `DataValueField` specified (You will have to change your query to return `CoffeeId` as well, but it's not required)

Comment: many thanks i worked the placeholder 'blank' default item. But the datafield worked perfectly. Again thank you. I will mark your answer correct when i can